# Unknown attribute android:layout_width, layout_height, id, gravity, layout_gravity and other attribute in xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, android-layoutparams

- Getting Unknown attribute error on all android tag.
- In layout XML,
  Auto suggestion is not showing all attributes (like `layout_width`,
  `layout_height`, `orientation`, orientation & all others android
  attributes.)

**here Things i have done to resolve this issue:**

> - Clean Build & Rebuild
> - Deleted .idea
> - file Invalidated Caches/Restart..
> - option Turn On Power Save Mode.

SDk is up to date.

my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: give us some more context. What layout/element are you using etc. Not all support all of these attrs

Comment: Hi tnx for response.i am using Constraint Layout and my xml can't recognize any attribute.

Comment: Do you have android namespace declared in your xml ?`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: Can you share your Xml code of layout maybe there is issue in namespace

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki yeah all is set

Comment: @IntsabHaider 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: @Benjamin would you please add this with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem just like you and I did all of things that you've done and here is my solution.
maybe problem is your targetSDKversion in gradle. if it is 28.0.0 you can change it to 27.1.1 and sync your project with gradle files.

this can help you to solve it.

Comment: downgrading targetSdk is really not a solution

Comment: @TimCastelijns hi yeah it is not really solution but it solved my problem.

Comment: @Benjamin well good luck fixing it again when you raise the targetSdk back to 28

Comment: @TimCastelijns i know it is not a reliable solution but it can help in diagnosing  problem so far we know that i have this problem in 28.0.0 not in other versions

Answer (score 0):

Change something in your app module build.gradle file, for example, comment a line, then
click `File` and then `Sync Project with Gradle Files`.